# Can you use document.writeln inside an HTML Object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, vlc

I'm trying to pass a parameter via URL to a webpage that displays a rtsp video stream in a vlc object.  The parameter is set as the "SRC" of the VLC object.  The second one (with the explicit URL works fine)  The object first object that uses the document.writeln does not work.  I put the same script code between the two

```
<script>document.write(getpar("IP"))</script>
```

and called the page like......

page.html?IP=rtsp://10.61.197.119

and it displays "rtsp://10.61.197.119" between the two VLC objects on the HTML page so I know my javascript function is working properly.  The only thing I can assume is the object doesn't play nice with embedded javascript??

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getpar(search_for) 
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var parms = query.split('&');
   for (var i = 0; i < parms.length; i++) 
   {
      var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
      if (pos > 0  && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) 
      {
         return parms[i].substring(pos+1);;
      }
   }
   return "";
}
</script>
<object
   classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
   codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
   width="1024" height="768"
   id="vlcPlayer1"
   name="vlcPlayer1"
   class="vlcPlayer"
   events="True">
   <param name="Src" value="<script>document.write(getpar("IP"))</script>" />
   <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
   <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
   <param name="controls" value="False" />
</object>

<script>document.write(getpar("IP"))</script>

<object
   classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
   codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
   width="1024" height="768"
   id="vlcPlayer"
   name="vlcPlayer2"
   class="vlcPlayer2"
   events="True">
   <param name="Src" value="rtsp://10.61.197.119" />
   <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
   <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
   <param name="controls" value="False" />
</object>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No, you've to write the whole tag instead. Or rather make this at server-side.

Comment: Is there a way to pull off what I'm trying to do (dynamically pass a rtsp URL to the object)?

Comment: @Teemu What do you mean by write the whole tag?

Comment: Umh ... `d.w('<object classid= ... ><param name="src" value="' + getpar(...) + '"><param ...></object>'`.

Comment: Umh....thanks.  :)